# Find minimum pair of numbers whose sum is 15

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers

I am trying to find the minimum pair of numbers to achieve sum of 15. I am creating new array for them and passing that array to method which is adding element of that array and generating true or false. array size will increase if method returns false.

```
public class FindMinimum {

    static int arr[] = { 10, 3, 2, 13 };
    static int numArr[] = new int[30];
    static int arrLength = 2;
    static boolean status = false;
    static int number;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
            numArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        if (checkPair(numArr)) {
            System.out.println("Number found");
        } else {
            arrLength = arrLength + 1;
            System.out.println("Increasing array length by one");
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkPair(int x[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            number = number + x[i];
        }
        if (number == 15) {
            status = true;
            for (int i : x) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } else {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

**Expected result** is minimum pair of addition that is "13 ,2"

Comment: And what exactly is the question? 1. Will the number always be 15? 2. Why is `numArr` declared with size 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly need to find minimum pair which always add to 15. If this is correct below code should solve it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i=0,j=arr.length-1;i<arr.length && j>=0;) {
            if ((arr[i]+arr[j])<15) {
                /*System.out.println(arr[i]+"-"+arr[last-i]);
                break;*/
                i++;
            } else if ((arr[i]+arr[j])>15) {
                j--;
            } else {
                System.out.println(arr[i]+"-"+arr[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what if combination of 3 integers achieving 15 sum. I want to find minimum pair (that could be pair of 2,3,4 numbers also)

Comment: i wrote this for a pair not for a set of numbers.

Comment: Could you please tell me what code should i write for if the pair contains more than 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMinimumPair {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int userArr[];
    static int numArr[]; // New array to take number / pairs from main array to compare with else numbers
                            // in the main array
    static int arrLength = 1; // increase the array length of numArr if pair is more than 2 numbers
    static boolean status = false; // check method returns true or false
    static int sum;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Sum of pair should be ?");
        sum = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the lenght of an array");
        int userArrLength = sc.nextInt();
        userArr = new int[userArrLength];
        System.out.println("Enter array integers upto " + userArrLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < userArrLength; i++) {
            userArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Loop to read numbers from main array
        for (int i = 0; i < userArr.length; i++) {
            // Defines the length of new array
            numArr = new int[arrLength]; // initialize the new array
            // Loop to add numbers into new array
            for (int j = 0; j < arrLength; j++) {
                numArr[j] = userArr[j]; // add numbers into new array
            }
            if (check(numArr)) { // call check method and pass new array in it
                for (int a : numArr) { // if returns true then print that array (contains the pair)
                    System.out.print(a + " ");
                }
                System.out.print(userArr[numArr.length]); // print the last number which is the part of numArr
                System.out.println(" is equals to " + sum);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Numbers not found");
            }
            arrLength = arrLength + 1; // increase the array length if false
        }
    }

    public static boolean check(int number[]) {
        int x = 0;
        // Loop to make sum of all numbers of numArr (make it single number)
        for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
            x = x + number[j];
        }

        outer: for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) { // loop for elements in numArr array

            for (int j = 0; j < userArr.length; j++) { // loop for given array elements
                if (x + userArr[j] == sum) { // check each number of given array with the sum of numArr
                    status = true;
                    break outer; // breaks outer loop and returns true
                } else {
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```